# How to enable pulg and hack feature in OWASP ZAP

Tags: owasp

I have recently downloaded OWASP ZAP to perform security testing. But there is no option for plug and hack feature so that I can incorporate it with Firefox? Can anyone tell me why is it not there and how can I add it?

ZAP version 2.6.0
Ubuntu 16.04

[No plug and hack feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAecP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because mozilla firefox has restricted plug and hack feature in new versions for security concerns.

If you still wish to do so, try using older firefox versions.

Answer (score 0):

The add-on used features that are now no longer available in Firefox, unless you trust unsigned add-ons. It is being reworked, but no eta I'm afraid.
You can still install it from the ZAP Marketplace - just click on the 'Manage Add-ons' button, 'Check for Updates' and search for 'plug' in the 'Marketplace' tab.

You can now also use the new 'browser launch' feature. Just make sure you're running the latest version of ZAP (currently 2.6.0) and that all of your add-ons are up to date. You'll then get the option to lauch any browser from ZAP, automatically configured to proxy through ZAP and ignore certificate issues. More details in this blog post: https://zaproxy.blogspot.com/2017/08/zap-browser-launch.html